# Javascript: simulate random execution time for the same function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I have an `askGoogle` function. I'm calling it 10 times in a loop. I'd like to make it so each call of that function takes a random amount of time. So that some calls get finished first:

```
Done with google 0
Done with google 3
Done with google 2
Done with google 8
Done with google 1
...
```

However I'm not sure how to do it. I tried to simulate it with the `setTimeout` method, but it seems to force the code behave synchronously, so all next calls to the `askGoogle` wait until the previous call has been finished.

```js
const https = require("https");

let i = 0;
function askGoogle()  {
    setTimeout(() => {

        const googleRequest = https.request("https://google.com", {
            method: "GET"
        });
        googleRequest.once("error", err => {
            console.log("Something happened!");
        })
        googleRequest.once("response", (stream) => {
            stream.on("data", x => {
            });
            stream.on("end", () => {
                console.log("Done with google " + i);
                i++;
            })
        })
        googleRequest.end();
    }, getRandomInt(0, 50_000));
}


for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    askGoogle();
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

How do I change it to achieve an output similar to the sample one above?

Comment: take a look into async functions, which when called occur in a separate thread 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: uh, no, @StarshipladDev, you are on the wrong track. async functions do *not* run in a separate thread. It's just syntactic sugar. JS is still single threaded unless you use worker threads. And, if anything, async allows you to `await` on async functions, i.e., make them appear sync again, which is the opposite of that the OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distilling your outer logic down to the essentials makes the error more obvious: It's the counter used in the output and when you increase it. Run this canonical example:

```js
let i = 0;
function askGoogle()  {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Done with google " + i);
      i++;
    }, getRandomInt(0, 500));
}

for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    askGoogle();
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

I would suggest passing `j` as an argument to the `askGoogle` function and printing that.

```js
let i = 0;
function askGoogle(j)  {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Done with google " + j);
    }, getRandomInt(0, 500));
}

for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    askGoogle(j);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Realized the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Your `stream.on("end", ...)` closures will always print "0, 1, 2,..." in order, even if the the googleRequest calls are out of order.

To have a quick fix:

```js
let i = 0;
function askGoogle()  {
    let j = i++;  // This way we are sure we are counting in order of calling askGoogle
    setTimeout(() => {

        const googleRequest = https.request("https://google.com", {
            method: "GET"
        });
        googleRequest.once("error", err => {
            console.log("Something happened!");
        })
        googleRequest.once("response", (stream) => {
            stream.on("data", x => {
            });
            stream.on("end", () => {
                console.log("Done with google " + j);. // j has been fixed before
            })
        })
        googleRequest.end();
    }, getRandomInt(0, 50_000));
}


for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    askGoogle();
}
```